# How do I store userinputs that I get from using getch();?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have this code set up to read what keystrokes the user has inputted. But my next part of my assignment asks me to then output what the user has inputted after the user hits the "~" key. For example if the user inputs ais6d9123~ then output ais6d9123. It is pretty simple, but I am confused on how to capture the keystrokes from getch(). I think I need to use a string and an array, but Im not quite sure how to implement it into what I have so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    char c;
    Node* next;
};

void main()
{
    char c;
    c = _getch();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `_getch` and `conio.h` are not parts of Standard C++ - wherever you are learning this stuff from, learn it from somewhere else.

Comment: `void main()` is not standard c++ so...., don't use it :), `std::string str; std::cin >> str; std::cout << str;`

Comment: use std:vector<string>  v and while((c= _getch())!='~') {v.push_back(c)}

Comment: You've included iostream twice btw.

Comment: @EladHazan: `_getch()` returns a character value. Why would you use a vector of strings?

Comment: I posted a solution - look there... vector of char

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    char c;
    Node* next;
};

void main()
{
    char c;
    vector<char> v;
    while ((c=_getch())!='~')
    {
        v.push_back(c);
    }

    for (std::vector<char>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        cout <<  *it;
    cout << '\n';

    system("pause");
}
```